# pyspark get element from array column of struct based on condition from a string value

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Spark DataFrame with the following schema as shown below

```
 |-- col1 : string
 |-- col2 : string
 |-- customer: struct
 |    |-- smt: string
 |    |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |     |-- key: string
 |    |    |     |-- value: string
```

df:

| col1 | col2 | customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1_XX | col2_XX | "attributes":[[{"key": "AUS 1", "value": "56"},{"key":"BS 1", "value": "45"}] |

I want an output where the value from the customer column will be taken only if the key is starting with A. I am unable to put regular expression, in this code line as shown.

```
df = df.withColumn('AUS',expr("filter(customer.attributes,x->x.key='AUS')")[0]["value"]
```

expected:

| col1 | col2 | customer | AUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col1_XX | col2_XX | "attributes":[[{"key": "AUS 1", "value": "56"},{"key":"BS 1", "value": "45"}] | 56 |

Getting:

| col1 | col2 | customer | AUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| col1_XX | col2_XX | "attributes":[[{"key": "AUS 1", "value": "56"},{"key":"BS 1", "value": "45"}] | null |

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `filter` function in a SQL-like statement with a substring function, to check only the first letter. Something like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("attributes", F.expr("filter(customer.attributes, x -> substring(x.key, 0, 1) = 'A')"))
```

This will filter only the ones that start with 'A'. You could also explode the column and apply the filter afterward:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("_map", F.explode("customer.attributes")).filter((F.col("_map").key.startswith("A")))
```

After that, you can iterate over your keys and create the columns as you need them (if they are not known beforehand).